# Resgatar valor de uma string em uma array

Tags: php, array

Como faço para pegar uma string dentro de uma array como a do exemplo a baixo:

```js
array(2) { 
    ["data"]=> array(1) { 
        ["charges"]=> array(1) { 
            [0]=> array(8) { 
                ["code"]=> int(433528162) 
                ["reference"]=> string(0) "" 
                ["dueDate"]=> string(10) "22/04/2019" 
                ["checkoutUrl"]=> string(100) "https://www.boletobancario.com/boletofacil/checkout/6E13300AFACDEE50594094562346gsfgwertE683D98BBE076EF" 
                ["link"]=> string(142) "https://www.boletobancario.com/boletofacil/charge/boleto.pdf?token=22904578:m:0bcf68c9aefc1f558218562a9efbad42bbefeabe82b248a437d66344950ba460" 
                ["installmentLink"]=> string(140) "https://www.boletobancario.com/boletofacil/charge/boleto.pdf?token=43188162:562c5278b4ac529291a711d461a721311b86da6ed1f0e02ba0e85848e0f37821" 
                ["payNumber"]=> string(54) "34190001275" 
                ["billetDetails"]=> array(4) { 
                    ["bankAccount"]=> string(12) "06" 
                    ["ourNumber"]=> string(14) "102-4" 
                    ["barcodeNumber"]=> string(44) "34196786700000012751094318816240655464808000" 
                    ["portfolio"]=> string(3) "109"
                }
            }
        }
    } ["success"]=> bool(true)
}
```

A que quero resgatar é a ["checkoutUrl"] para fazer um redirecionamento;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ola! para pegar o valor vc precisa acessar as chaves do array. Assuma que a variável $array é onde está guardado o valor do array acima. Neste caso:

```
$checkoutUrl = $array["data"]["charges"][0]["checkoutUrl"];
```

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
        $array = [
        'data' => [
            'charges' => [
                0 => [
                    'code' => 433528162,
                    'reference' =>'',
                    'dueDate' => '22/04/2019',
                    'checkoutUrl' => 'https://www.boletobancario.com/boletofacil/checkout/6E13300AFACDEE50594094562346gsfgwertE683D98BBE076EF',
                    'link' => 'https://www.boletobancario.com/boletofacil/charge/boleto.pdf?token=22904578:m:0bcf68c9aefc1f558218562a9efbad42bbefeabe82b248a437d66344950ba460',
                    'installmentLink' => 'https://www.boletobancario.com/boletofacil/charge/boleto.pdf?token=43188162:562c5278b4ac529291a711d461a721311b86da6ed1f0e02ba0e85848e0f37821',
                    'payNumber' => '34190001275',
                    'billetDetails' => [
                        'bankAccount' => '06',
                        'ourNumber' => '102-4',
                        'barcodeNumber' => '34196786700000012751094318816240655464808000',
                        'portfolio' => '109',
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'success' => true
    ];

    echo $array['data']['charges'][0]['checkoutUrl'];
```